# Error in C program in Dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, function

I am using gcc compiler in ubuntu18.10 os. And I don't know why this program is giving Error and Can't even understand the error. The Program is as follows and I presented ERRORS also.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

float Average(int*, int);

int main()
{
 int *arr;
 int n;
 scanf("%d",&n);
 float sum;
 arr = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);

 sum = Average(int *arr, int n);
 printf("%f\n",sum);
 return 0;
}
float Average(int *arr, int size)
{
  int sum;
  int n = size;
  printf("arr: %p\n",&arr);
  printf("size: %p\n",&size);
  printf("sum: %p\n",&sum);

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    sum += arr[i];
  }
  return (sum * 1.0f) / size;
}
```

Errors are:

```
Test.c: In function ‘main’:
Test.c:16:16: error: expected expression before ‘int’
  sum = Average(int *arr, int n);
                ^~~
Test.c:16:8: error: too few arguments to function ‘Average’
  sum = Average(int *arr, int n);
        ^~~~~~~
Test.c:4:7: note: declared here
 float Average(int*, int);
       ^~~~~~~
```

Please Help me to find out why and any reference materials to understand the concept clearly.
Thank you

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note other compilers use different options to output the same things.  Note: the posted code causes the compiler to output 6 warning and 2 error messages.

Answer (score 2):

```
sum = Average(int *arr, int n);
```

Type specifiers are something you give in the declaration and definition of the function, *not* in calls to it. You want:

```
sum = Average(arr, n);
```

---

Some other things you may want to check.

First, the `int sum;` in `Average()` does *not* initialise the value to zero, it sets it to some arbitrary value. That's not going to end well when you just add the integers to it. It should instead be:

```
  int sum = 0;
```

Second, unless you're using massive arrays of floating point numbers, it's almost always better to use `double` for its greater range and precision.

---

Taking those into account, I probably would have written the function:

```
double Average(int *arr, int size) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        sum += arr[i];
    return sum / size;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So, failed to call the function properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function you don't specify the types of the arguments.  That's a syntax error.  If you look at where you call `printf`, you'll see that you don't specify the parameter types there.  The same goes for your own functions.

So change this:

```
sum = Average(int *arr, int n);
```

To this:

```
sum = Average(arr, n);
```